# Redefine nil in smalltalk to respond any message

Tags: smalltalk, null, pharo, method-missing

I want to redefine smalltalk's **nil** to work like the one in *objective-c*. So when **nil** receives a message that it can't handle, it returns *nil*. Now I know that `nil` is just a shortcut for `UndefinedObject` but is there anything like `method_missing` in *Ruby* so I can redefine it in `UndefinedObject` to always return *nil*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method you are looking for is called `doesNotUnderstand:` in Smalltalk. You can indeed implement:

```
UndefinedObject>>doesNotUnderstand: aMessage
    ^ nil
```

However, keep in mind that this affects the complete system and might have subtle side effects or introduce bugs in other parts of the system.

Also note that `UndefinedObject` is not a primitive type, but a normal class inheriting from `Object`. Therefor `nil` already understands a large number of messages and might not behave as you would expect coming from Objective-C.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it. I know that it can break the system, but I just want to try :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating your own Null singleton class that implements #doesNotUnderstand: so that you don't modify nil. Make the super class nil (like Object).

Answer something like '^Null instance' instead of '^nil' in cases where you want it.

```
Null instance badMethod  --> nil
```

Comment: that won't work. For example I want to close and destroy a connection. But if a new connection wasn't assigned to a variable, I'll send `close` to `nil` and I don't want to check if it's `nil` or not. I want to close it or do nothing.

Comment: True... a null object is intended for your own code; it's a pattern we've found it useful. You can always add #orNull to UndefinedObject to answer null and to Object to answer self. Then your code could be 'x := self connection orNull'.

Comment: Comment by Bob Nemec makes perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

If you're the only person who will ever work on this code, I say go for it.

On the other hand, if this is a product owned by some company which is not a synonym for "you", and someone else may at some time have to maintain this, I strongly recommend that you NOT do this.  Modifying classes at the heart of Smalltalk is one of THE classic ways to blow your toes off.  (I knew a guy once who did this.  He was *not* happy...and always limped a bit after that.  Funny old thing, life...).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks, I know that stuff. I juts wanted to make some experiment, as I was doing my homework

Comment: In that case, dive in and have a ball!  :-)